# why my code of inplace recursion of character array is not working for all the test cases? is there any problem with my code

Tags: java, recursion

```
class Solution { 
    static int k=0; 
    static int l=0; 

    public void reverseString(char[] s) { 
        if(k==s.length||s==null){ 
            return; 
        }

        char c = s[k++]; 
        reverseString(s); 
        s[l++]=c; 
    } 
}
```

why my code of inplace recursion of character array is not working for all the test cases? is there any problem with my code

Comment: I'm assuming that you're not using this in a multi-threaded environment so it doesn't matter here. But don't store those ints as static ints. If you're going to require class variables (which you don't) then store them regularly

Comment: But for the actual problem. Try putting comments so you can say what you think your code is doing. Also this isn't in place, every instance of recursion is still storing variable c.

Comment: Please provide the input for which the following code is not working

Comment: On SO it is best if you can post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) rather than a [Fix my code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40164/should-we-close-fix-my-program-questions) post. Your question is on the write track, but some editing, especially of the question title, could make it more clear.

Comment: You should check whether `s is null` before you use its `length`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a class that has to be instantiated to reverse the array, I would suggest the following:

```java
class Solution {

   public static void reverseString(char[] str) {
      reverseStringImpl(str, 0);
   }

   private static void reverseStringImpl(char[] s, int k) {
      // details here
   }
}
```

I omitted the details (but the array and starting location are sufficient to accomplish this).  This is still recursive but it hides the implementation and does not require any `instance variables` to maintain `state`.  Nor does it require the user to pass the initial starting location of `0` to the method.